# How to retrieve matching element in array in spring mongodb ?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Im trying to retrieve a document with a specific '_id' and a single embedded document with another specific '_id'.

my document is represent a catalog and it contains an array of courses.

example data:

```
'_id': ObjectId('1111'),
'name': 'example catalog',
...
...
'courses': [
     { 
         '_id': ObjectId('2222'),
         'name': 'my course',
         ...
     },
     {
         ....
     }
```

In mongod I run this aggregation query, and get back what I wish for:

```
db.getCollection('catalogs').aggregate(
{ $match: { '_id': ObjectId('58e8da206ca4f710bab6ef74') } },
{ $unwind: '$courses' },
{ $match: { 'courses._id': ObjectId('58d65541495c851c1703c57f') } })
```

As I mentioned earlier, I've get back I single catalog instance with a single course instance within.

In my java repo, I was trying to do the same:

```
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(Catalog.ID_FIELD).is(catalogId)),
            Aggregation.unwind(Catalog.COURSES_FIELD, true),
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(Catalog.COURSES_FIELD + '.' + Course.ID_FIELD).is(embeddedCourseId))
    );
    AggregationResults<Catalog> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,
            Catalog.class, Catalog.class);

    List<Catalog> catalog  = results.getMappedResults();
```

But unfortunately, I've got an instance of my 'example catalog' with empty array of courses.

While debugging, I've found that inside `results`, there are two props that returns back. 
first one is what I've used, called `mappedResults` (represents the converted object returning from mongoDB) - contains an empty array of courses.
the other one is the `rawResults`, (represents the data as `DBObject`) - **contains the specific course I query for**

*my Catalog class contains an ArrayList (if that make any difference).*

Please help and let me know what should I do to convert the results properly, or if I did something wrong in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below options. The key is to preserve the structure when mapping the response.

**Regular Queries:**

Using [$positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) projection

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId("58e8da206ca4f710bab6ef74")).and("courses.id").is(new ObjectId("58d65541495c851c1703c57f")));
query.fields().include("name").position("courses", 1);
List<Course> courses = mongoTemplate.find(query, Course.class);
```

Using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId("58e8da206ca4f710bab6ef74")));
query.fields().include("name").elemMatch("courses", Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("58d65541495c851c1703c57f") ) );
List<Course> Course = mongoTemplate.find(query, Course.class);
```

**Aggregation**

**Mongo Version >=  3.4** & **Spring 1.5.2 Boot / Spring 1.10.1  Mongo.**

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage which will overwrite the `courses` field with the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) value while keeping all the existing properties. I couldn't find any `addFields` builder in current spring version. So I have to use `AggregationOperation` to create a new one.

```
AggregationOperation addFields = new AggregationOperation() {
    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
        DBObject dbObject =
                new BasicDBObject("courses",
                        new BasicDBObject("$filter",
                                new BasicDBObject("input", "$$courses").
                                        append("as", "course").
                                        append("cond",
                                            new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.<Object>asList("$$course._id", new ObjectId("58d65541495c851c1703c57f"))))));
        return new BasicDBObject("$addFields", dbObject);
    }
};

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("58e8da206ca4f710bab6ef74"))),
            addFields
 );
```

**Mongo Version =  3.2** & **Spring 1.5.2 Boot / Spring 1.10.1  Mongo.**.

The idea is still same as above but this pipeline uses [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) so you'll have to add all the fields that you want to keep in final response. Also used spring helper methods to create the `$filter` pipeline.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
     Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId("58e8da206ca4f710bab6ef74"))),
     Aggregation.project("name")
                 .and(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("courses").as("course")                          
                 .by(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("course._id").equalToValue(new ObjectId("58d65541495c851c1703c57f")))
                    ).as("courses")
 );
```

**Mongo Version <= 2.6**

You'll have to use `$unwind` and add a `course` field to have spring map it correctly.

Comment: Hi Veeram, thanks a lot, I've implemented my code using the projection instead of unwind & match - and it's worked just fine :)

Comment: You are welcome. Added couple of more non aggregation based options because you're matching on _id for courses and is always unique. `$filter` is  general approach when you have more than one matching entry in arrays.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggested edits. Appreciated. I was just working off different example here.

Comment: Actually, I did a generic method that filter Courses by any field. but still thank you for adding that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have here is that your `Catalog` class has a `courses` field which maps to a `List/ArrayList`. But when your aggregation query unwinds the courses array, it is going to output the `courses` field as a sub-document. The Spring mapper doesn't know how to deal with that because it doesn't match your `Catalog` object structure.

You haven't fully defined your problem here, but what would probably make more sense is if you had the aggregation return a `Course` object rather than a `Catalog` object. In order to do that you're going to need to add a projection stage to your aggregation pipeline so that the result looks exactly like a single Course object. The key is that the data coming back from MongoDB needs to match your object structure.