# Spring Data MongoDB: search like on multiple fields

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection containing User objects with two fields: Firstname and Lastname. I need a query that takes only one string (representing the user fullname) for a findLike research.

The problem is the same of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662413/select-records-matching-concat-value-of-two-fields-in-mongodb) but I do not know how translate that query for a MongoDB Repository in Spring Data using MongoTemplate or @Query annotation

EDIT:
Using project operator i have to specify all fields I want include in the stages. A better solution maybe could be use `AddFields` operator:
A similar question I found is that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40812293/6545142

How can I use the `$AddFields` operator with MongoTemplate?

Comment: What is your mongo version ?  You can check running `db.version()` in shell.

Comment: @Veeram the version is 3.4.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) ( 3.6 mongo version operator ) to use aggregation functions in regular query for only exact matches.

Spring `@Query` code

```
@Query("{$expr:{$eq:[{$concat:["$Firstname","$Lastname"]}, ?0]}}")
ReturnType MethodName(ArgType arg);
```

For find like searches or exact search you've to use aggregation via mongo template in lower versions.

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project().and(StringOperators.Concat.valueOf("Firstname").concatValueOf("Lastname")).as("newField");
```

**for like matches**

```
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("newField").regex(val));
```

**for exact match**

```
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("newField").is(val));
```

Rest of the code

```
 Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, match);
 List<BasicDBObject> basicDBObject =  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, colname, BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: It works but returns me an object with all attributes set on null, only the Id is set...

Comment: Add all the fields in the project stage that you need to keep in the response. Something like `project("field1", "field2")`. Change to your pojo class from BasicDBObject for mapping

Comment: My pojo class has really many attributes, and adding all the fields in the project stage is not very nice. I found a better solution with $addFields operator instead of project. My query looks like: `{$addFields: {'newField': {$concat:["$field1"," ","$field2"]} } }, {$match: {'newField':'value'}}` . How can I use it with MongoTemplate?

Comment: I wanted to suggest that but there is no helper for addFields just yet and wanted to know what your requirement was. So just need to use AggregationOperation to create a new stage. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43326515/2683814) is such  example.

Comment: Thank you! Through AggregationOperation I create the addFileds operator, and now it works properly