# UncategorizedMongoDbException: 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use positional projection in aggregation projection'

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm getting this error on my service method :

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 31324 with name 'Location31324' and error message 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use positional projection in aggregation projection' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 31324 with name 'Location31324' and error message 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use positional projection in aggregation projection' on server localhost:27017
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:3048)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2984)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2670)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2652)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:902)
    at AlertService.getAlertByUserLogin(AlertService.java:90)
    at AlertResource.findAlertsByUser(AlertResource.java:32)
```

My method looks like this :

```
Document alerts = new Document();
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("users.userId").is(userLogin));
query
    .fields()
    .include("name", "condition", "locationId", "ruleId", "severity", "timestamp", "users.$");
query.with(pageable);
List<Alert> result = mongo.find(query, Alert.class, "alert");
```

I want the query to return all matching documents. `users.$` is used to return only the matching object and not return all the array of objects.

Comment: Try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329833/3710490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329833/3710490)